# Inheriting css styles

Tags: css

Following is the two css.

I want `helpContent` to have all the styles of `itemContent`. How would I make `helpContent` to inherit `itemContent`?

```
.itemContent {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #ababe3 1px solid;
    BORDER-TOP: #ababe3 1px solid;
    DISPLAY: block;
    PADDING-LEFT: 3px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px;
    PADDING-TOP: 3px;
    OVERFLOW: hidden;
    BORDER-LEFT: #ababe3 1px solid;
    WORD-WRAP: break-word;
    POSITION: static;
}
.helpContent {
    BACKGROUND: #eff5ff;
}
```

Comment: class="itemContent helpContent"; with SASS you can do it with @extend, but with pure css ou have to copy/paste it...

Comment: @philipp Put it as an answer quick, before the vultures come :p

Comment: No that means the div would have 2 css. I want helpContent inherit itemContent. something like .helpContent {
    BACKGROUND: #eff5ff; itemContent;
}

Comment: @Zenith the answer below is also very good!

Comment: Why are you using upper-case property names?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be

```
.itemcontent, .helpcontent  {
    border-right: #ababe3 1px solid; 
    border-top: #ababe3 1px solid; 
    display: block; 
    padding-left: 3px; 
    padding-bottom: 3px; 
    padding-top: 3px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    border-left: #ababe3 1px solid; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: static;
}
.helpcontent {
    background: #eff5ff; 
}
```

Comment: Side note, ignore UPPERCASE

Comment: I've copied the css code from the question and just changed it to make inheritance

Comment: No worries :) I did it for you

Answer (score 0):

and the shortest way would be:

```
.itemcontent, .helpcontent  {
    border: 1px solid #ababe3;
    border-bottom: none;
    display: block; 
    padding: 3px 0 3px 3px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: static;
}
.helpcontent {
    background: #eff5ff; 
}
```